# Sort each columns of a sparse Matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I'm wondering if I could sort each columns of a sparse Matrix(using the "Matrix" package) fast. The sparse matrix is about 10,000 x 10,000.

examples:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   1    .    .     .
[2,]   2    2    .     .
[3,]   .    1    .     1
[4,]   .    .    1     2
```

result:

```
    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]   2    2     1     2
[2,]   1    1     .     1
[3,]   .    .     .     .
[4,]   .    .     .     .
```

I found some info saying that the data stored in sparse Matrix may be col-based, and only non-zero element are stored, so I am wondering if there is a fast method to just sort these data.

I'm totally a newbie, is there the fast way or can I manipulate the data using Rcpp since I'm more familiar with cpp. Thanks a lot.

---

Edited:

using apply(cosMat,2, sort), the benchmark is shown below:

```
    Unit: seconds
                             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq    max neval
 cosAns <- apply(cosMat, 2, sort) 1.741451 1.854026 1.877813 1.871355 1.896548 2.0143   100
```

Comment: something like apply(matrix, 2, sort) maybe?

Comment: Have you tried to sort your sparse matrix columns directly? Since only non-zero elements are stored, it could be already doing what you want in a fast enough way (I guess). Cheers.

Comment: @Niek I have tried using apply, but it is quite slow, about 1.87minutes.